# SSD1351 Corruption: USB to Pico RAM to SSD1351 buffer issue

Tags: usb, spi, rp2040

I'm trying to get a Raspberry Pi Pico connected over USB to a Pi 4 receiving the correct image data in its RAM, which is converted into a 128x128x2byte image (RGB565 color) using get_image.py (I've verified this works just fine and the output is exactly what I would expect on the Pi 4 side).

I am then trying to write this image data to the SSD1351 display over SPI. I am not using tinyUSB but instead using a get_char_timeout() without working explicitly with the tinyusb stack. The Pico is waiting for a S before it runs the SSD1351_write_image() and SSD1351_update() functions, which I've listed below as well for clarity.

The expected result at the moment is that the image data is corrupted. All of the image seems to be there but the color data looks wrong:

[image: Color pixel issue]

```
bool receive_start_string() {
    char start_str[] = "TART";
    int start_str_index = 0;
    int data;

    while (start_str_index < strlen(start_str)) {
        data = getchar();
        if (data == start_str[start_str_index]) {
            start_str_index++;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

    void serial_thread(void) {
    // Set up the variables
    char serial_input = '\0';
    int i = 0;
  
      // Check if there's any serial input available
      if (stdin && !feof(stdin)) {
          // Try to read a character from the serial input
          serial_input = getchar();

          // Variables for game end message
          char end_str[] = "END";
          int end_str_index = 0;

          // Check if the character is 'X'
          if (serial_input == 'X') {
              multicore_reset_core1();
              return;
          }

          if (serial_input == 'S') {
              if (receive_start_string) {
                SSD1351_write_image(); 
                SSD1351_update();
                // multicore_reset_core1();
                return;
            }
          }

          else if (serial_input == 'E') {
              if (receive_end_string()) {
                // multicore_launch_core1(display_stats);
                SSD1351_fill(COLOR_WHITE);
                SSD1351_update();
                // multicore_reset_core1();
                return;
              }
          }
      }
}
```

```
void SSD1351_write_image(void){
  SSD1351_clear();
  int i = 0;
  while (i < DRAM_SIZE_8) {
    int data = getchar_timeout_us(100);
    if (data != PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT) {
        image_buffer[i++] = (uint16_t)data;
    }
  }
  sleep_ms(100);
  memcpy(DRAM_8, image_buffer, DRAM_SIZE_8);
}
```

```
void SSD1351_update(void){
  SSD1351_write_command(SSD1351_CMD_WRITERAM);
  SSD1351_write_data_buffer(DRAM_8, DRAM_SIZE_8);
}
```

Overall, my project code base can be found here:
https://github.com/StonedEdge/Retro-Lite-CM4-Dock/tree/main

Does anyone see specifically a reason why this would be happening and could kindly suggest a way to improve the code so that this is avoided? I've already configured my hardware to send the data over the Pi 4 from USB so ideally I would like to get this working over USB if possible. Data is being sent to the RP2040 over a serial connection. The way the SSD1351_write_image function currently works is it reads the serial data sent over from the Pi 4 and then stores it in a buffer. This buffer is then sent to the OLED buffer after calling SSD1351_update().

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `getchar_timeout_us(100)` surely returns 8-bit data (`uint8_t` or `char`), yet you're copying it into your `image_buffer` array as if it's 16-bit `uint16_t`. The higher order 8 bits of every element in your array will be zero.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I tried removing the casting and it didnt change anything. Anyone else can help?

Comment: The problem isn't just the type-casting of `data`, it's the fact that you never put any data into the most-significant byte of every element in your array. When you're receiving data and loading it into the array,  you need to be indexing into the array as if it's an array of `uint8_t` not an array of `uint16_t`. Something like `((uint8_t *)image_buffer)[i++] = data;` should work.

Comment: Or alternatively, just declare the array as `uint8_t` type (and twice the size) instead of `uint16_t`.